# TypeError: one$2 is not a function on svelte-kit build

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a basic blog based on Sveltekit. On my Ubuntu 20.04 dev server, `svelte-kit build` works well with `adapter-static`. But I find that any remote environment I try to deploy to triggers the same error, `TypeError: one$2 is not a function`.

Because it works in one place, but not in others, I thought it must be an environment-related bug. But so far, it's failing *everywhere* else:

- Gitlab Pages / Review apps (with `adapter-static` in `node:lts-alpine`)
- Cloudflare Pages (with `adapter-static`)
- Netlify (with `adapter-netlify`)

So it's probably my code :D

Does Sveltekit have any way to debug (what I guess are) compile errors like this? The cli options are pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

This was something--that I haven't yet nailed down--to do with npm dependencies in a utility js file used by Svelte endpoints. I refactored very slightly and managed to eliminate the error.

I'm still in the dark really.

Comment: Can you check the NodeJS version on the environments being built on? SvelteKit works well on NodeJS 14 and up